# Change All users passwords - Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have Server 2008 and we have around 250 users, we need to change 200 accounts passwords all to the same thing temporarily.

What is the easiest way to change all 200 accounts passwords?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 1):

With a script:

[See this article](http://computerperformance.co.uk/ezine/ezine170.htm) on how to do it in powershell in various methods.  You do need to get the [Quest Ad cmdlets](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx) for this example.  Under a full 2008 environment you may not need them but I almost prefer them to the MS ones

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a way of doing this programmatically via Powershell or vbscript - sorry I can't provide a script!

There are loads of bits of free software out there for doing this - usual caveats apply though (don't put it in live straightaway!)